# C How to take String and Int from file and put at 2D Array

Tags: c, string, file, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if I could take string and int from a txt file and put in 2D array, so I can edit the file with that 2D array later on.

My code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Max_Name_Chars 20
#define Max_Accounts 100
#define Max_Chars_Per_Account 100

void getDataBaseText(FILE* Database,char * Array_Name_Money[Max_Accounts][2]);
void saveDataBase(FILE* Database,char * Array_Name_Money[Max_Accounts][2], int Line_Counter);
void setDataAtDatabase(FILE* Database,char Name[Max_Name_Chars], int Money);

int main()
{

    FILE* Database = fopen("Database.txt", "a+");

    setDataAtDatabase(Database,"Big",100);

    fclose(Database);
    return 0;
}

void getDataBaseText(FILE* Database,char * Array_Name_Money[Max_Accounts][2])
{
    int Charcters;
    int Line_Counter = 0;
    int Char_Index = 0;
    int SwitchIndex = 0;
    while ( (Charcters = getc(Database) ) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d",Char_Index);

        if (Charcters == '\n') {
            Line_Counter++;
            Char_Index = 0;
            SwitchIndex = 0;
            continue;
        } else if (Charcters == ':') {
            Char_Index = 0;
            SwitchIndex = 1;
            continue;
        }

        Array_Name_Money[Line_Counter][SwitchIndex][Char_Index] = Charcters;
        Char_Index++;
    }
}

void setDataAtDatabase(FILE* Database,char Name[Max_Name_Chars], int Money)
{
    char * Array_Name_Money[Max_Accounts][2];
    getDataBaseText(Database,Array_Name_Money);

    int Line_Counter;
    int FoundName = 0;
    for (Line_Counter = 0 ; Array_Name_Money[Line_Counter][0][0] ;Line_Counter++ )
    {
        //printf("%s\n",Array_Name_Money[Line_Counter][0]);
        if (strcmp(Name,Array_Name_Money[Line_Counter][0]) ==0 )
        {
            FoundName = Line_Counter;
            break;
        }
    }

    char DataBase_Money[Max_Chars_Per_Account];
    sprintf(DataBase_Money, "%d", Money);

    if (FoundName)
    {
        Array_Name_Money[FoundName][1] = DataBase_Money;
    } else {

        Array_Name_Money[Line_Counter][0] = Name;

        Array_Name_Money[Line_Counter][1] = DataBase_Money;
    }
    saveDataBase(Database,Array_Name_Money,Line_Counter);
}

void saveDataBase(FILE* Database,char * Array_Name_Money[Max_Accounts][2], int Line_Counter)
{
    fclose(fopen("Database.txt", "w"));
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= Line_Counter ; i++)
    {
        fprintf(Database,"%s:%s",Array_Name_Money[i][0],Array_Name_Money[i][1]);

        if (i != Line_Counter)
            fprintf(Database,"\n");
    }
}
```

My problem that in the function "getDataBaseText" it doesn't take the full chars from the txt file as it takes only "Big:1"

my txt file: `Big:100`

All I wanna do is to take a string and int and put it at the file if the name does not exist, but if the name does exist so I wanna set a new value of money in the txt file, I had searched for taking 2D arrays from file, but there was any problem like mine.

Comment: You try to write to strings that have no memory attached; a `char *` on its own is just a pointer without storage attached.. `Array_Name_Money` is not initialized and will have indeterminate contents. And I think you shouldn't do the database operations on the file directly. Load the data into an array at the beginning, inspect and modify the data as you like, then commit the changes to the file again. Working on data in memory is much easier.

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE* Database = fopen("Database.txt", "a+");`  When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "fopen failed" );`  then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 0):

Suggest:

Input a whole line from the file, perhaps using a large buffer and the function: `fgets( largeBuffer, sizeof largeBuffer, fp)`  where 'fp' is the file pointer from `fopen()`

Then use `strtok( buffer, ":")` to get a 'token' pointer to the leading string

Then use `if( strcmp( token, "Big" ) == 0 )` check if the current line is the one of interest

If the current line is the one of interest

Then use `strtok( NULL, ":")` to get a 'token' pointer to the numeric value

Then use `sscanf( token, "%d", &number )` to save the number to a `int` variable